# If I don't get recognized for my achievements and ideas, am I more likely to find progression by starting at a new place?

Tags: politics

If I identify a constant pattern of my work and ideas not being recognized, others taking full credit for achievements I enabled, and even ignoring me - could it mean that I will never be successful at my current job in terms of career progression and will likely find more luck at a job elsewhere?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is impossible to know.

Comment: Why is it impossible to know? Are there no experience-based patterns in this kind of situations?

Comment: Some places may have executives that can see through someone taking someone else's credit, other places may not be that involved. Some places may have promotions and other places may have you at a dead end if the company doesn't grow for a long time. What could happen is a lot of different possibilities that to properly assign probabilities that are realistic would be beyond a Ph.D. thesis paper to my mind. Keep in mind you state nothing about what kind of work you do other than there are achievements which is true of most jobs that exist.

Comment: If the problem is within yourself and if the problem is your attitude, the problems you will encounter on your next job will most likely be very much the same as the problems you are experiencing in your current job. At this point, you have not given us enough information for us to make any determination as to whether the problem is you or your management/employer.

Comment: @YtrewQ - there are, but the problem is that there are a few patterns that may apply. Nobody here knows the root cause, so we'd only be guessing - not answering the question. I would wager though that if you're not being recognized for your work and ideas - it's because you're not selling or marketing them well/enough.

Comment: Can you please give some examples?

Comment: How is this off topic? I think the wording could be framed more generally around "How to get noticed in your organization", but off topic?

Comment: @Bmo, et al. This could be made more on-topic if the asker can provide more details about the specific problem. With the amount of information and the way the question is worded, one must speculate and guess at what the exact details are. Check out the [link from the close reason](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695) for more guidance, if anyone wants to help with editing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

From my own experience, my answer to you would be "I doubt it".

I work in a large organization, I do a lot of work in the background. I'm the technical guy not the process guy. So in a project that is say, improving some traffic flow problem I get pulled into help them crunch data and make reports to monitor their output but am rarely mentioned in the presentation to management.

Why? Because I was passive...too passive. It took a while to realize but you're going to have to stand up for yourself and be a bit more assertive.

I really, really wanted my work to speak for me (I still feel that it should have) but I don't think that's how the workplace is most of the time.

Also, I've seen some people take credit for my work innocently. They felt like they designed something having given me all the information. I started bringing people in on the development process, they got to see that it was more complicated than just copy and pasting things from this website. When they got to see the innards of their project and the work I was doing for them I started to get the credit I deserved.

To summarize, if you're passive now. You're likely going to be passive at another job. Occasionally you need to give yourself a bit of self promotion. When you get some momentum and exposure and the kudos you've rightfully earned it gets easier.

Comment: People take credit often because they know the person who did the work won't take it himself and so they won't get caught. If you don't play the political game, you lose. 100% of the time - at all companies.

Answer (score -4):

Let's assume you are right in your assessment of situation, as you have more information.
It sounds like you are weak in politics and your colleagues are strong in it. You can try to train in politics... or find another job, where politics doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Personal history isn't really an answer without more general evidence/examples - to counter: both times I've moved companies were side-steps, while both promotions I've had were internal.

Comment: You are none too clear as to what you were looking for in the new job that you were not getting in your current job, how you made sure that you were getting the changes you wanted when you interviewed, and what else you did to make sure that changing jobs worked for you. Throwing out solutions without going into detail as to why they work is acting like the Oracle at Delphi - That does not help those of us who are clueless about interpreting oracles (continued)

Comment: Those who read your answer are not necessarily looking for answers as much as they are looking for guidelines as to why and how your answer works. At which point, they can apply the guidelines to their situation.